# TeamCity Github one project works, the other does not

Tags: git, teamcity

Both vcs roots show success when testing the connection, but one always errors on:

`git fetch` command failed

I did notice that with the project that fails, when I do git bash, I must do `git pull origin master` instead of just `git pull`. I made sure both config files under the `.git` directories are identical (except for the url, of course). I am new to git...

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with TeamCity but if this turns out to be a git problem, you might want to try the following:

- Run `git remote -v` and make sure the URLs are correct.
- Run `git branch -vv` and verify the branches have valid upstreams, e.g. [origin/master].
- Verify permissions and ownership of all files and directories under .git, both locally and remotely.  I remember having fetch issues caused by bad ownership but I'll admit this looks unlikely in your case.

If that doesn't help, see if you can give us more details, like extra error logs around the "'git fetch' command failed" message.

Comment: git remote -v looks correct (git pull works fine)
git branch -vv (both repositories look the same * master id ....)

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: 'git fetch' command failed.
 stderr: Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: Remote does not have refs/heads/origin available for fetch

Comment: In your `.git/config` file, make sure the remote section's fetch setting says `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, and if that still doesn't work you might have to re-clone the repo from scratch because that error message you're getting basically says your `origin` remote's specs are wrong.

Comment: rebuilt the repository and somehow the config is ok now... still not sure what it was, but is was the config as you said. Thx

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you set `origin` in the branch field of VCS root settings, so TeamCity tries to fetch branch `refs/heads/origin` which doesn't exist. Try to set `master` there.